# How to check if a field exists in all the rows of a given dataframe

Tags: pyspark

My dataframe has fields (X, Y, Z) -> But few rows of the dataframe do not have the field 'Z'. I have a check like this presently

```
if not 'f' in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn('f', <>)
```

But cases, when certain rows has the field and certain other rows do not have the field - how do I check for that?

Note: 
"Z" can either be "null" or have some_value. And there can be cases when there is no Z field at all.

Comment: If you filter the dataframe using df['Z'].isNotNull(), this will return the rows with all fields exists for Z

Comment: But there might be cases when Z exists but it's value is "null" -- will update the question with the same.

Comment: "there is no Z field at all" = null  , if the filed Z is not there it will be null. The schema for Dataframe is fixed, in your case it is X,Y,Z. So all rows will have X,Y,Z either nulls or values.